# How to get which key was pressed in react-native app, while take input in text box?

Tags: react-native, onkeypress

I have been trying to make chips of the input on pressing "enter" by user. How could I achieve that in react-native environment? I am trying to use "onKeyPress" event but not providing solution.

Here is my code:

```
<Input style={formCSS.textFieldInput} onKeyPress={(keyPress) => console.log(keyPress)} placeholder='Hobbies' />
```

Picture of desired result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to doc, `onKeyPress`

> Callback that is called when a key is pressed. This will be called
>   with { nativeEvent: { key: keyValue } } where keyValue is 'Enter' or
>   'Backspace' for respective keys and the typed-in character otherwise
>   including ' ' for space. Fires before onChange callbacks. Note: on
>   Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not the
>   hardware keyboard inputs.

So you should use it like

```
onKeyPress={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.key)}
```